# Calculate percentage of change between multiple pairs of columns grouped by another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
VAR1   OCT20 NOV20 DEC20 JAN21 ...
x      1     1.6   2.4   3.3
y      2.1   1     0.7   5.4
z      2     3.1   0.5   2.1
```

What I want to compute is, per row in the VAR1 column, the percentage of change between each month (one month compared to its previous, not all possible pairs).
So e.g. for `x: pct_change` between OCT20 and NOV20, then NOV20 and DEC20 etc. Then the same for `y`.

Any help on how to do this?

Comment: pivot table, then use pct_change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the index and use pct_change

```
df.set_index('VAR1').pct_change(axis=1)

      OCT20    NOV20    DEC20     JAN21
VAR1                                   
x       NaN  0.60000  0.50000  0.375000
y       NaN -0.52381 -0.30000  6.714286
z       NaN  0.55000 -0.83871  3.200000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['VAR1','OCT20', 'NOV20', 'DEC20','JAN21'],
['x',1,1.6,2.4,3.3],
['y',2.1,1,0.7,5.4],
['z',2,3.1,0.5,2.1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
df = df.T.iloc[1:]

print(df.pct_change())
```

Answer (score 0):

here you can use shift

```
df_per = (df-df.shift(axis=1))/df.shift(axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is not the correct way to calculate percent change.